# Terminology: is there a term for one order being on a geodesic between two others in the Cayley graph?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, permutations

Think about the graph whose nodes are total orders on a finite set, and whose edges connect orders that only differ on two elements.  This is actually a Cayley graph of $S_n$, but I don't want to fix a preferred origin (let me abuse notation and call it a Cayley graph anyways).  One condition that comes up in Coxetery stuff all the time is that one order $<$ is on a geodesic from $<'$ to $<''$; this is equivalent to there being no pair $a,b$ with $a< b, a>'b$ and $a>''b$.
Unfortunately, I've never seen a name given to this condition on total orders, even though it's a very natural notion.  It would be helpful for me to have one.

> Have you seen this notion defined anywhere?  Does it have a consensus name?

Comment: I don't think this is a consensus name, but it would seem natural to me to say that $\le$ *interpolates* $\le'$ and $\le''$.